# Unable to push Android Studio Project to Github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I've recently got introduced to GitHub. I created a Project and shared it on GitHub. Before that, I've already installed git and Git Bash. I am able to commit changes but can't push it from Android Studio. It gives *Permission denied* error.

[image]

I tried pushing from the command line (Git Bash) using

`git push origin master`

but same error. After searching I found a workaround

`git push https://github.com/user/project master`

But I am unable to figure out what's wrong because it gets difficult to sync my project properly with Android Studio

Comment: As message shows you have some sort of permission issues. Try checking your keys.

Comment: have you tried to logout and login again? maybe your permission session expired and need to renew

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting your remote url and push.

following is the command for changing the remote

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

Comment: Please recheck the url